# Prevent iOS swipe back to the login page or destroy the login page after login

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using react native with expo to write a apps.
It work on Android version, but I found that it have problem in iOS version.

After I login the apps, from login page to home page. In Android when I click on back button, it display the logout reminder to user.

However it iOS, we don't have back button, user usually swipe back instead of click back button.
But I found that when user swipe right in my apps, no matter in which page, it will have chance back to the login page.

So it's possible to destroy the login page to prevent back to login page in my apps?

Comment: if you use React navigation this might help https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/

Comment: Which navigation are you using?